# Pass a shared_ptr to OpenGL?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I have code that would normally function like this:

```
char* log = new char[logLength];
glGetProgramInfoLog(..., ..., log) 
//Print Log
delete [] log;
```

How could I achieve the same result with a C++11 Smart Pointer? Who knows what could happen before I have a chance to delete that memory.

So I guess I need to downcast to a C style pointer?

Comment: by the way the smart pointers are not a C++11 exclusive ...

Comment: This does not answer your question, but I would simply use a `vector<char>` as in [this example](https://github.com/progschj/OpenGL-Examples/blob/master/01shader_vbo1.cpp#L49).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your code really looks like that in your snippet, `shared_ptr` is a bit of an overkill for the situation, because it looks like you do not need shared ownership of the allocated memory. [`unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) has a partial specialization for arrays that is a perfect fit for such use cases. It'll call `delete[]` on the managed pointer when it goes out of scope.

```
{
  std::unique_ptr<char[]> log( new char[logLength] );
  glGetProgramInfoLog(..., ..., log.get());
  //Print Log
} // allocated memory is released since log went out of scope
```

Answer (score 3):

`std::shared_ptr` has a method [`get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/get) which you can use to get a C style pointer to the variable. If that pointer is to a `std::string`, you need to further call the `c_str()` function to get a pointer to C style string.

edit: I notice the function  is writing to the string as opposed to reading. You would need to resize the std::string first, and even after that, [the pointer returned by c_str  isnt meant for writing](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/c_str/). std::shared_ptr should work though.

Comment: For writing you can use &str[0]. In C++11 it's guarateed to work (standard requires continguously allocated storage)